# Liquification of ideal solution of two liquids from vapor phase

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, phase, gas-phase-chemistry, liquids

A and B form an ideal solution. In a cylinder piston arrangement, $\pu{2.0 mol}$ of vapor of liquid A and $\pu{3 mol}$ of vapor of liquid B are taken at $\pu{300 torr}$ and $T~\pu{K}$. At what pressure $30\%$ of the total amount of substance of vapor will it liquefy? Given $\ce{Pa^{.}}=\pu{300 torr}$,  $\ce{Pb^{.}}=\pu{600 torr}$, ($\sqrt{48.25}=6.95$). Kindly provide a conceptual and brief solution with an explanation.
The answer comes out to be $\pu{445 torr}$. This question is from a preparatory-test for The indian jee Advanced exam, And i think it can be a discussion. As i put my input into it already, i dont think this should be a homework-question, But instead, it raises a thought and creates new perspectives

Comment: You first. What have you done so far?

Comment: i tried raoult`s law, daltons law. Didnt get answer. I actually dont know what to do with external 300 torr presurre given in question.And Should i consider that after 30% of vapours are liqufied, now equillibrium between external pressure and internal pressure is established??

Comment: No.  The 300 torr initial pressure is increased to a higher final pressure.  You need to find out what that final pressure will have to be to end up with 30% liquid at the same temperature T.  I think that the initial pressure of 300 torr means that the initial vapor is not saturated.

Comment: got that..How can i proceed with equations now. Because thats where i lack now. My equations earlier had no use of given numerical estimation, which indicates i might be at wrong path. Can u please write them?

Comment: Please [edit] in your attempt of solving the exercise. Please also explain what ist actually given.

Comment: @om Makadia. 1) What is the meaning of Pa* and Pb* ? 2) What is the meaning of the number 48.25 which appears as a square root without any explanation ?

Comment: hey maurice, pa* and pb* are vapour of pure A and pure B. And there is no meaning to any number. These are approximations one has to use while solving, So that u dont have to calculate the sqaure root yourself. Also, u aint getting a calculator in indian exams. So these approximations are given to u. 

Comment: I have tried for a week everyday to solve this question and then i have came here. Why does it close my question??

Comment: *And i think it can be a discussion.*  // Note that, in contrary to various web forums and other interactive platforms, the format of the StackExchange sites is being question + answers site, they are not primarily intended as discussion platforms. There do exist chat rooms, but they are separated form  the particular Q/A pages. // Comments are not intended for discussion either, they can be deleted or moved to a chat room.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- $L$ is the amount of substance of liquid
- $V$ is the amount of substance of vapor
- $x$ is the mole fraction A in the liquid
- $y$ is the mole fraction of A in the vapor

Total amount of substance:
$$L+V=5\tag{1}$$

Amount of substance of A in liquid plus vapor:
$$Lx+Vy=2\tag{2}$$

Raoult's Law:
$$y=\frac{300x}{300x+600(1-x)}=\frac{x}{2-x}\tag{3}$$

Fraction of total amount of substance that is liquid:
$$\frac{L}{L+V}=0.3\tag{4}$$

So, from Eqns. 1 and 4, we have $L = 1.5$ and $V = 3.5$.  Substituting these results and Eqn. 3 into Eqn. 2 gives:
$$1.5x+\frac{3.5x}{2-x}=2,$$
which leads to the quadratic equation $$1.5x^2-8.5x+4=0.$$

Solving this quadratic equation for $x$ using the quadratic formula:
$$x=\frac{8.5-\sqrt{48.25}}{3}=0.517$$
This gives $$P=300x+600(1-x)=300(2-x)=\pu{445 torr}.$$

Comment: you Are a GOAT ...... I was stuck for almost a week....

Comment: thanks martin too.✌